# Laptop suspends during boot up

Tags: boot, suspend, power-management

When I boot this 5th generation X1-Carbon (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3 with kernel 4.12.5) the computer will suspend in the midst of the boot process.  The LED in the power button flashes slowly.  Boot will not proceed until I hit the power button again.

Recently the computer started suspending immediately at the conclusion of the boot process.  Once woken up all is well, computer wakes from suspend mode without problems.  I generally only reboot the machine when required to do so by an update so it'll go days and days of normal suspend/awaken.  The issue only occurs on bootup.  I've never tried hibernation on this machine (a.k.a. suspend to disk).

I've searched repeatedly but nothing I've tried has affected this behavior.  Does anyone know where the config file resides that contains these settings?

Thanks,

Don

Here is part of /var/log/syslog.  The boot process starts at 06:22:12.  There were two suspends which I get past by pressing the power button.  By 06:22:59 the bootup is proceeding to completion.  My interpretation of this info is that somehow a very short timeout has become the default, but I'm guessing about this.  It's certainly not something I ever changed or edited.  Sorry if the formatting comes out wrong.  Each new line starts with "Aug 31" should you need to arrange it into a more readable shape.

```
Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:12 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: gnome-session gave us a dead inhibitor: /org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor1
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1270]: gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1270]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for power management...
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon bluetoothd[1170]: Terminating
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1112]: (gnome-settings-daemon:1133): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1112]: gnome-session-binary[1112]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1112]: gnome-session-binary[1112]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1112]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session[1112]: (gnome-shell:1158): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gnome-session-binary[1112]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1122]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1122]:       after 25 requests (25 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (II) evdev: ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Close
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1103]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon bluetoothd[1170]: Stopping SDP server
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon bluetoothd[1170]: Exit
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gdm3: Tried to look up non-existent conversation gdm-launch-environment
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon gdm3: Freeing conversation 'gdm-launch-environment' with active job
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user gdm.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping Disk Manager...
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for generating UUIDs...
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1252]: Stopped target Default.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1252]: Reached target Shutdown.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1252]: Stopped target Basic System.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1252]: Stopped target Paths.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1252]: Stopped target Sockets.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1252]: Stopped target Timers.
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Aug 31 06:22:14 x1-carbon rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="748" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="775" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-modules-load[248]: Inserted module 'lp'
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-modules-load[248]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-modules-load[248]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Mounting Configuration File System...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Mounted Configuration File System.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon loadkeys[250]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon ureadahead[257]: ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlp4s0.conf: No such file or directory
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9"
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8"
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-sleep[399]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-sleep[401]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-sleep[399]: Suspending system...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Found device /dev/disk/by-uuid/d150a877-72ab-43a4-a02a-2375542118b2.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d150a877-72ab-43a4-a02a-2375542118b2...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Found device /dev/disk/by-uuid/de520869-178f-4c47-b7ac-472683b93c9f.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/de520869-178f-4c47-b7ac-472683b93c9f...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 340 (plymouthd).
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-fsck[465]: /dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 41296/14057472 files, 20108830/56223062 blocks
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/de520869-178f-4c47-b7ac-472683b93c9f.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d150a877-72ab-43a4-a02a-2375542118b2.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-sleep[399]: System resumed.
Aug 31 06:22:59 x1-carbon systemd-sleep[569]: /lib/
```

The log file goes on quite a bit further from here but the output above is what I think is the relevant part.

Sept 1 -
Here is more from the log file.  This begins prior to the portion above.  I had suspended the computer, woke it up, and then rebooted a few minutes later.  You already have seen the portion of the boot log.  Again, all lines begin with 'Aug 31'

Comment: Search for events in /var/log/syslog. Usually, they are all stored there. Other log files are useful, as /var/log/Xorg.0.log, if these issues are related to video driver.  I suggest you to watch your laptop and annotate exact time when it will suspend, so you may inspect at this time at syslog what happened.

Comment: I took your advice.  Here's the output from part of /var/log/syslog this morning:

Comment: Apparently there's no harmful error at these piece of your log. May the cause happened before it. Paste syslog from the beggining till 6:22:12